# Randonly Named DLL use in legitimate programming

Tags: c#, dll

So, this is a very general sort of question.  How often does one see a totally random name for a DLL in legitimate (as in, not malware) programming?  Is it common practice to generate DLLs on-the-fly through CSC.exe during program installation, for example?  Or should this be viewed as a good indicator of malicious activity or intent?  Thanks for any insight this awesome community provides!

Comment: Pretty sure this is off topic for SO and belongs on the [programmers stack exchnage](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The old JIT compiler for ASP.Net (1.0, 1.1) used to produce a set of random named dlls when it ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile code at runtime using `CSharpCodeProvider` for things like user executed code the files it generates will be randomly named dll's by default in your temp folder.

Also when downloading dll's for a plugin type system you may have randomly generated names so two plugins don't get a name collision.

Basically if you can think of a legitimate reason your program would use user generated code there is a possibility that the user generated code will be randomly named to prevent name collisions.

Comment: good answer, thanks!